# iTextSharp - Add two text lines to existing PDF

Tags: javascript, itext

I've a printing workflow that allow me to call aand execute external JScript to help the printing process.
So, I need to add some information to all PDF pages, [image: example] on the fly.
I'm trying to set up with iTextSharp following the tips/examples from [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs-itext5/header-and-footer-examples) and [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-watermark-pdfs-using-text-or-images), but without success.

Any help will be very appreciated

Thanks in advance

Carlos

Comment: The tips you mention are written in Java (with iText, not iTextSharp). Have you found any resource for JScript?

Comment: Hi C.Champagne, ah ok ;), I'm completly noobie with this, and no, I don't find any resource for JScript :(. I read a lot of information and google a lot but I don't find any kind of help ....

Comment: So what are you looking for, an itext solution or a javascript one?

Comment: Hi mk, a javascript.

Comment: iText exists in 2 flavors: Java and C#.
There is no javascript version.